# iOS UITableView "'Attempt to create two animations for cell'"

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-animation

I have a customTableView cell - I want to just update on cell (based on a network event occuring).

So when I first make the network call I do:

```
 - (void)makeNetworkCall
 {

      [self.tableView beginUpdates];

      // MAKE_NETWORK_CALL

      [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


       [self.tableView endUpdates]; // SIGABRT OCCURS HERE ON SECOND CALL
 }

 - (void)networkDataReturned:(NSDictionary*)dataReturned
 {
     // UPDATE_TABLE_VIEW_DATA_MODEL       

     [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

  }
```

This works perfectly the first time the network event is called, however if the cell is tapped (thus calling the network event again, the result of which has now been cached) I get the following error:

```
2011-06-22 11:19:11.262 App[3991:707] *** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimationsForExistingVisibleCells], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1448.89/UITableViewSupport.m:288
2011-06-22 11:19:11.327 App[3991:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to create two animations for cell'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x32c7664f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x36eb9c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x32c76491 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 68
    3   Foundation                          0x32894573 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 62
    4   UIKit                               0x35f59d3b -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForExistingVisibleCells] + 402
    5   UIKit                               0x35f58b81 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport initWithTableView:updateItems:oldRowData:newRowData:oldRowRange:newRowRange:context:] + 296
    6   UIKit                               0x35f57dc1 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateWithItems:withOldRowData:oldRowRange:newRowRange:context:] + 972
    7   UIKit                               0x35f57473 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 4750
    8   UIKit                               0x35f612f9 -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 28
    9   UIKit                               0x35f612d5 -[UITableView endUpdates] + 16
    10  App                             0x0005a033 -[CustomTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 574
```

Answer (score 56):

To anybody that encounters this situation again, make sure there are not repeated indexPaths in the array being passed to reload, delete or insertRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: Great reply! Spared me a lot of wasted time investigating tangents, while missing the relatively obvious.  IMO, Apple should improve the error message text to include your hint.

Comment: I didn't have repeated paths but wrong numbers for sections (a bug caused the section to be set as `(NSUInteger)-1`). Anyway, your answer pointed me to the solution, thanks.

Comment: It also should be noted that this does not crash on iOS 9+.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error by telling tableview to reloadSection twice.

Answer (score 2):

It’s hard to understand how you’re causing that error message, but try moving your table reload code into a separate method, and call that where you have the two identical code blocks now. That might fix what seems to be some sort of weird race condition that `UITableView` is supposed to filter out on its own anyway.

Comment: See @jjramos reply below.  It's probably a less ominous less convoluted situation than it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Assume `self.arTableData` is a mutable array of table & `tableView` is an instance of `UITableView`.  Assume there are 10 rows ( which means 10 objects in array ) in `tableView`.
I do implement following code to remove rows animated.

```
int i; // to remove from 3 to 6
for(i=2;i<6;i++)
{
    [self.arTableData removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

If you want multiple row deletion, try to remove rows one by one & not all at once. 
Deletion of multiple rows ( including animation ) might cause crash.

But while you are inserting rows, you can pass entire array to insert & UITableView will surely perform animation.

That trick works for me without any hassles. Hope it work same for you. Best of luck.

Comment: @Spark if you add [self.arTableData beginUpdates] before the loop and [self.arTableData endUpdates] afterwards, it will batch all the delete operations into a single animation

Answer (score 1):

I got this for trying to remove row with index -1 in a section.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have a table view of restaurants with their distance to user's current location. The distance will be updated when it receives new user location. This causes cells to be updated at certain moments. If the user re-order the cells happen to be the same time as cells are being updated. one cell will be manipulated from two positions. This caused the program crashes. So I just check if it is edit mode, don't update the distance. I hope this might help. This is one specific condition of the answer from @jjramos